# WPF: XAML Custom Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF: XAML Custom Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669560/wpf-xaml-custom-namespace)

Okay so I have a Window in WPF. I add the following line inside of it:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mCubed.Controls"
```

This compiles and runs just fine, but the Visual Studio designer gives me this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'mCubed, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I remove this line from the Window, it compiles and runs just fine and the Visual Studio designer works like a charm!

I'm confused as to why that one line breaks the designer? This occurs ***REGARDLESS*** if I have put the following line in the body of the XAML document.

```
<controls:MyControl/>
```