# WPF: XAML Custom Namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

Okay so I have a Window in WPF. I add the following line inside of it:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mCubed.Controls"
```

This compiles and runs just fine, but the Visual Studio designer gives me this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'mCubed, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I remove this line from the Window, it compiles and runs just fine and the Visual Studio designer works like a charm!

I'm confused as to why that one line breaks the designer? This occurs ***REGARDLESS*** if I have put the following line in the body of the XAML document.

```
<controls:MyControl/>
```

All my .cs files are in the same VS project. I have a mCubed namespace which contains my cleverly named mCubedWindow class. I have all my controls classes defined in the mCubed.Controls namespace. Do NOT tell me this is an assembly problem, ALL MY FILES ARE IN THE SAME VS PROJECT!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an assembly problem, just a designer problem. The VS WPF designer in 2008 is primitive at best - completely useless IMHO. I turn it off completely and use the XML editor instead. Hopefully things will improve drastically in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Is MyControl in the same assembly as the window? If it isn't, you need to include the assembly name in the declaration:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mCubed.Controls;assembly=mCubed"
```

Comment: Its in the same Visual Studio project so I guess. It compiles and runs with no problems, so I dont think that's the problem. It shouldn't even compile if that were the case.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit weird. I've developed several projects that do exactly that. Here's a quick dummy project, all in one .exe:

First, a `UserControl` with a couple of buttons:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Width="30">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left">A</Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">B</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now the main window, with my control added to it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <p:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

No error messages anywhere.

Comment: I've put my custom controls into a Controls folder in my project if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is the XAML loose (Build action: None, No code behind) or compiled (Build action: Page, Can have code behind)?

If the XAML is loose or if MyControl is in a different assembly you must specify which assembly MyControl is in, like Daniel Pratt stated:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mCubed.Controls;assembly=mCubed"
```

Make sure the assembly mCubed and its dependencies (references) are copied to your output directory. If they are not, then add mCubed as a reference to the start-up project.