# Create .NET component like Windows Search Toolbar

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

Does anyone know the way to create on .NET (better with c#) control inside taskbar?
There is a good utility for time-management, LazyCure, but it's a little more than needed. As it's free, I want to create a minimize look, and this variant now is the better for me.

Image how it should look like - below.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can create a custom control that visually and functionally resembles a Windows Vista-style search box.** This will work in any .NET WinForms project, including C# or VB.NET; just drop it on to a form and wire up the relevant event handlers.

Here's an excellent tutorial: http://coderjournal.com/2007/03/creating-a-vista-like-search-box/

I don't really understand what you're asking regarding LazyCure. I haven't heard of it, but the way I read the question, you just want to use a search box in your re-implementation of a similar utility. If so, the above method will work fine for you.

If you are hoping to place the control in the Windows Taskbar, that's going to be a *lot* more difficult. You might look at the following articles for some suggestions on how you might go about accomplishing this:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/statusbar/taskbarctrl.aspx

Or you could simply place your application's icon in the taskbar's [Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx) so it is always easy to access, like the volume control or some other common utility programs. The [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component provided as part of the .NET Framework makes implementing this functionality very simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using wpf the toolbar will accept any control, including your own custom controls.

#### Edit:

First, have a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752063.aspx) on wpf's toolbar. Toolbar is quite simple to use, and the documentation explains it pretty well.

Basically, you just create an instance of your custom control as a content item of the toolbar. In the examples in the documentation, the content items are `Button` but it could be any other control.

If you need an example of how to create an instance of your custom control in XAML, including declaring the appropriate namespace, see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669560/wpf-xaml-custom-namespace). His question says he's having a problem, but his code and example is correct--it was entirely VS2008's error.

Comment: Hm. Now it's on 4.0, so WPF may be good. Could you please explain a little more, how to install my custom control as part of taskbar?

Comment: Read what I added below "Edit"