# Trigger to hide text when image source is valid (not null)

Tags: .net, wpf

[image: three rows, the first and third with no image, and the second with an image]

So I've got a DataGrid with an image column and I want to be able to hide the "Browse..." hyperlink when the Image has a valid (non-null) Source. How can that be done?

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">Browse...</Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Oh, and if there's an easier way to achieve an image button with alternate text, please let me know! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make TextBlock invisible by default and write Trigger for `Image.Source == null`

Something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">Browse...</Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Image Name="Image" Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Image"
                                     Property="Source"
                                     Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter TargetName="TextBlock"
                                        Property="Visibility"
                                        Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the code snippet - makes a lot more sense that way!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ValueConverter to bind the Image to the Visibility.  A simple converter that works based off of null would look like this:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility True { get; set; }
    public Visibility False { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value != null ? True : False);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can create a couple of instances of this in your XAML resources to use to control the visibility of the elements.  Also, you don't need to template the Button since WPF buttons can contain anything you'd like them to (not just text).  So your XAML could look something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <loc:VisibilityConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" True="Visible" False="Collapsed"/>
    <loc:VisibilityConverter x:Key="BrowseConverter" True="Collapsed" False="Visible"/>
</Window.Resources>
. . .
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Visibility="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource BrowseVisibility}}">
                        Browse...
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0"
                        Visibility="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageVisibility}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note that you'll also need to [create the loc namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669560/wpf-xaml-custom-namespace) at the top of your XAML.  And I assumed you'd be putting these in your Window resources.